# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: when trying to parse JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps

I'm trying to get data from the google maps distance matrix api via JSON url request, parse the data and place it into an input field to enter into my mysql database. I am able to complete the request and the JSON data is showing in my Chrome console but I am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token:" and nothing is being placed into the input field.

This is my code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json",
  type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
        cache: false,
  data: {
    units: "metric",
    origins: $("#autocomplete").val(),
    destinations: $("#fullAddress").val(),
    key: "mykey"
        },
  success: function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var distance = json[distance.value];
      $('#distance').val(data);
  }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` implies that the API doesn't support `JSONP`.

If I change `JSONP` to `JSON`, I get a different error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin is therefore not allowed access.
```

Google's Web Services are intended to be used from a server.  If you want to access them from javascript on the client, use the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

[example in documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/sq9znugy/2/)

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  $("#button").click(function() {
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
      origins: [$("#autocomplete").val()],
      destinations: [$("#fullAddress").val()],
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status !== 'OK') {
        alert('Error was: ' + status);
      } else {
        var originList = response.originAddresses;
        var destinationList = response.destinationAddresses;
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
        for (var i = 0; i < originList.length; i++) {
          var results = response.rows[i].elements;
          for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
            outputDiv.innerHTML += originList[i] + ' to ' + destinationList[j] +
              ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' +
              results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
          }
        }

        var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
        $('#distance').val(distance);
      }
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="button" type="button" value="click" />
<input id="autocomplete" value="New York, NY" />
<input id="fullAddress" value="Newark, NJ" />
<div id="output"></div>
<input id="distance" />
```

Comment: Hi I tried putting it together in a file but I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at test.php:48" line 48 being: google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize); please help